# Map from one dictionary to another using automapper

Tags: c#, dictionary, automapper, asp.net-core-3.1

I have not been able to find a solution to this while using automapper.
My problem is that I have a source Dictionary, and I need to "map" the source Dictionary to a new Dictionary where the keys should be different (basically "change" the keys of the source Dictonary)
I figured that I might be able to use AutoMapper for this.. so I tried the following:

```
private Source source = new Source
        {
            { "Name", "Frodo" },
            { "LastName", "Bagginz" },
            { "Years", 32 }
        };

        [TestMethod]
        public void CanMapDictionaryDictionaryUsingAutoMapper()
        {
            var configuration = new MapperConfiguration
            (
                cfg =>
                cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
                .ForMember(m => m["FirstName"], o => o.MapFrom(s => s["Name"]))
                .ForMember(m => m["Surname"], o => o.MapFrom(s => s["LastName"]))
                .ForMember(m => m["Age"], o => o.MapFrom(s => s["Years"]))
            );
            var mapper = configuration.CreateMapper();

            var result = mapper.Map<Destination>(source);

            Assert.IsTrue(result.ContainsKey("FirstName"));
            Assert.IsTrue(result.ContainsValue("FirstName"));
            Assert.IsTrue(result.ContainsKey("Surname"));
            Assert.IsTrue(result.ContainsValue("Surname"));
            Assert.IsTrue(result.ContainsKey("Age"));
            Assert.IsTrue(result.ContainsValue("Age"));
        }
    }

    public class Source : Dictionary<string, object>
    {
    }

    public class Destination : Dictionary<string, object>
    {
    }
```

Created the two classes just to make sure that we dont just map all dictionaries in our application once the MapperConfiguration is moved to a Profile and the Profile is loaded "globally".

However.. the above ends up with the following error:

> Message:
> Test method DictionaryMapperTest.MapDictionary.CanMapDictionaryDictionaryUsingAutoMapper
> threw exception:
> AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException: Custom configuration for members is only supported for top-level individual members on a
> type.   Stack Trace:
> ReflectionHelper.FindProperty(LambdaExpression lambdaExpression)
> MappingExpression`2.ForMember[TMember](Expression`1 destinationMember, Action`1 memberOptions) <>c.<CanMapDictionaryDictionaryUsingAutoMapper>b__1_0(IMapperConfigurationExpression cfg) line 23 MapperConfiguration.Build(Action`1 configure)
> MapperConfiguration.ctor(Action`1 configure)
> MapDictionary.CanMapDictionaryDictionaryUsingAutoMapper() line 20

Am I missing something? Does anyone have a better solution for doing the kind of "mapping" Im trying to achive above? Im kind of stuck.. and since all my other mappings in the application utilizes AutoMapper, it would be nice to be able to be consistent and keep it all in one place.

Comment: The intent is that I have a Json from a request body, and the property names needs to be mapped to other names so that tve json later on can be sent to a different system. I could achive this by simply using strongly typed objects and automapper, however.. the Json is supposed to be sent as a PATCH method, and if I serialized a strongly typed object with properties that are unset I would end up with default values in my serialized json. In a PATCH request that would actually update my resource with the default values, and thats why I cant use a strongly typed class/object..

Comment: And just to add to the above.. a Json property with a value of Bull would actually set the property in the system to null. While of the property does not exist in the sent Json, then the system Will not change that property value. I know there is also JsonPatch thats a format of doing this and that there is support for this in asp.net / .Net core, sadly I cant use that since not all JsonPatch operations are implemented in the system Im integrating to.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I don't recommend using a Dictionary to store these values. A class with properties (`FirstName`, `LastName`, `Age`) makes a lot more sense than a dictionary with the property names as keys.

Having said that:

You've defined your `Source` and `Destination` which are both `Dictionary<string, object>`. If you want a class which will map `Source` to `Destination` with the same values but different keys, this class will do it:

```cs
public class DictionaryMapper
{
    private readonly static Dictionary<string, string> keyMap;

    static DictionaryMapper()
    {
        keyMap = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "Name", "FirstName" },
            { "LastName", "Surname" },
            { "Years", "Age" }
        };
    }

    public Destination MapSourceToDestination(Source source)
    {
        var destination = new Destination();
        foreach (string sourceKey in keyMap.Keys)
        {
            if (source.ContainsKey(sourceKey))
            {
                var destinationKey = keyMap[sourceKey];
                var destinationValue = source[sourceKey];
                destination.Add(destinationKey, destinationValue);
            }
        }
        return destination;
    }
}
```

I used a few extra lines and variables to make it easier to see what's happening.

It stores the mapping of one key to another in a dictionary. Given the source, it looks at all the keys in the dictionary. Those keys are the "source" keys - that is, keys in the source dictionary.

For each key, if the source dictionary has that key, then it's going to look up the destination key in the `keyMap` dictionary, and add the value from the source to the destination dictionary using the key it retrieves from `keyMap`.

The output is a `Destination` dictionary with the same values as the source dictionary but with the new keys.

Even if this can be done with Automapper, you'll likely find this easier to read.

The class and all its methods could be `static`. I don't know how you're using it, so adjust according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks I will customize the above to my needs and try it out.